# Why does a bounty cost so much?

Tags: discussion, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the lower bound of a “bounty” be smaller?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19980/can-the-lower-bound-of-a-bounty-be-smaller)

I want to point out that why bounty could be start according to the suggested points by Stack Overflow. It could be user defined how much a user wants to  start with. If I have a question of 10 reputation so why should I start bounty with 100 or 50.

Comment: How are you sending the rest of the question? TV broadcast?

Comment: @Matt what do you meant?

Comment: Your question ends with: *so why i will s*

Comment: @RTA: Have you re-read your question? It makes no sense. And ends with a half sente

Comment: I think I have discovered why your Stack Overflow questions are not getting good answers...

Comment: @Matt oooo i just correct that one

Comment: How you judge your own question?If you have any problem and unable to solve yourself question is bigger for you.But for others may be its simple.So don't try to judge your own question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Bounties are considered special.

If users were able to place trivial amounts of reputation for bounties, everyone would to it in order to seek attention for their questions. This in turn would render the concept of bounties useless — imagine a place where every unanswered question had a little bounty on it …

[image]

I personally wouldn't like that, and it would even discourage users from looking at "featured" questions if there were too many of them, with too little incentive for answering those.

---

Remember that everyone here works hard for their reputation, so you need to earn the privilege to place a bounty first. And don't forget, if you post a really good question, it's easy to get back a little reputation from upvotes on it later, once you place a bounty.

Comment: **THAT** is a whole lot of featured questions right there....

Comment: It's even over 9000!

Comment: @slhck its not for you.Sorry. its for ... I correct my mistake.

Comment: What 9000?! There's no way that can be right.