# Special acknowledgement and collection of extraordinary answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, voting

I have just read [an answer on Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/16001/5396) which left me with the feeling that we all have had on occasion: I wish I could upvote this more than once.

It would be nice if there was a mechanism to highlight such answers, beyond the generic site mechanisms like upvotes and accepts. A button like "Awesome answer" (also question?) which would propel the answer to a board of joyful reads if clicked often enough (and award the poster a badge). Such a collection of exceptional posts could potentially rival Munroe's *What If.*

Since such praise should be exceptional it would be fine if a user could only award it only once in a while.

Is there something like that? If not, would it be worth the effort to implement it?

Comment: There is a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279816/mechanisms-for-recognizing-exceptional-answers) which focuses on rewards and bounties though; by contrast, I'd like to single such answers out with a new feature.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to draw more attention to an answer, consider *sharing* it; on your profile (which will be read network-wide), on social media or on your own website/blog. If you use the 'share' link underneath the answer, you can even earn [a badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer) for this if you attract enough visitors. (The badge description says you need to share a question; this is wrong, [it works for answers as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188733/295232).)

Other than that, communities are free to organize a contest in an (often featured) post on their own meta sites. Monica mentioned this already in the answer to the similar question you've found; there does not need to be a bounty involved. Puzzling Stack Exchange does it for [questions](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6547/11110) (which can't be awarded bounties) and it works quite well.

A separate feature for this doesn't really add any value in my opinion. One can already read extraordinary answers by [searching for `is:answer`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer).

Comment: "A separate feature for this doesn't really add any value in my opinion": I obviously and respectfully disagree ;-). As I said, it would be like "what if". Btw, what does sarching "is:a" do? Search for answers (whose "relevance" is by default the vote count)? In any case I'm not impressed by the result. Among other issues vote count heavily favors old questions. While that would to a degree apply to an "awesome" button count as well, votes are more indiscriminate and propel questions which are just helpful but boring and not awesome.

Comment: Indeed, it searches for answers only (`is:answer` works as well, but is more typing). You can use advanced criteria to search for new answers only. I fear that a 'hall of fame' would also favour old questions (after a few years anyway).

Comment: I'd expect you to disagree (otherwise you wouldn't have posted this question) but on Meta we're allowed to have different opinions :) I didn't downvote your question BTW.

Comment: No worries (and thanks for the correction edits).