# Recognition for Answers that Save Lives

Tags: feature-request, answers

**We should have an explicit feature for recognizing/rewarding/glorifying answers that save peoples' lives.**

The OP of [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/3125/12142) over at Great Outdoors commented in the accepted answer several years later stating that the advice given in the answer ***literally saved their life.***  Aside from feeling that the question and answer are criminally under-voted, I also feel that there should be some kind of **extra-special reward** for this kind of answer - some kind of "Medal of Honor" or other commendation bestowed only for these kind of stories.  Perhaps a way to report it to the Stack Overflow Blog so that it can be written about in a news story for all to see.

While this sort of answer is more likely on a site like Great Outdoors than on Stack Overflow, I still think it applies to all of Stack Exchange.  In a more general sense, life-saving stories like this are **the ultimate example of Stack Exchange's mission statement** of helping people.  I can think of no greater type of success story, and so I believe the reward should be proportionately exceptional.

Comment: Blog Overflow was originally designed for similar things, but unfortunately, nobody used it and it was eventually deprecated.

Comment: If someone has sufficient rep on the site in question, they can always award a bounty (and comment why they've done so).

Comment: @Glorfindel I don't think that question is very similar.  My request is not related to being "well-referenced" or otherwise high-quality, but rather, "life-saving (literally, in real life)".  Totally different.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to link to [Special acknowledgement and collection of extraordinary answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322929/295232). The answer you mentioned was very helpful, but we do not know what would've happened if the OP hadn't read the answer. Life-saving is a rather exorbitant claim for an internet post.

Comment: And you couldn't help it that your post was migrated from MSO. Thank you for cleaning it up yourself.

Comment: @Glorfindel I understand and accept how voting works here on Meta.  Thanks for explaining it anyway, though.

Comment: I've upvoted not because I agree that there should be a special reward but because I agree with the sentiment behind your request. I think the greatest reward is actually knowing that an answer posted on the Internet helped save someone's life. What could possibly surpass that? A badge and imaginary points would succeed in only trivialising it. I think the greatest service is sharing this piece of news and reminding each and everyone of us that we can have a positive affect on people's lives.

Comment: How can we verify that it truly saved someone's life? This seems too easy to fake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How could it be verified that the post had actually saved a life? There really is no system in place to verify anything that has happened outside Stack Exchange, much less something that has happened offline.

If one could receive the ultimate badge, a "Medal of Honor", for a post that saved someone's life, it would certainly create a lot of problems with dishonest people faking posts/comments about their own answer saving someone's life. **The biggest problem with this imo is that since it is so extremely rare that a post actually saved someones life, most of the holders of this badge would've probably faked it.**

Comment: There is "Hall of Fame" in the [security area of se.com](https://stackexchange.com/about/security). Maybe something similar can be done for proved cases of life saving answers.

Comment: @ShaWiz Check my last sentence, just edited that in.

Comment: The security Hall of Fame is itself pretty "rare" in that there's only a couple dozen entries total.  That doesn't mean that any portion of them are faked, nor does it reduce its value.

Comment: @SouthpawHare Completely different thing. How could someone fake that they have found a security vulnerability?